# Ruby 2.0 throws "[BUG] Stack consistency error"

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

I'm following the exercises from [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/) and in `about_proxy_object_project.rb` there's this bit of code:

```
class Proxy
  def initialize(target_object)
    @object = target_object
  end

  # This method was added by me
  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
    @object.send method_name
  end
end
```

That gets called like this:

```
def test_tv_methods_still_perform_their_function
  tv = Proxy.new(Television.new) # Television is a class with a :channel attr_accessor and a power method

  tv.channel = 10
  tv.power

  assert_equal 10, tv.channel
  assert tv.on?
end
```

The problem is that the line `tv.channel = 10` is "breaking" the interpreter and throwing:

```
[BUG] Stack consistency error (sp: 53, bp: 54)
ruby 2.0.0p0
(...)    
full stack trace follows
```

I've tried the same code with Ruby 1.9.3 and it's working. I'm using Ruby 2.0.0-p195.

So, is this an error/bug? Or I'm doing something horribly wrong?

Comment: It seems to have been fixed in p247 released on June 27, as pointed out by matt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is a Ruby bug in `ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-linux]`. At the end of the stack trace, it says:

```
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

<strike>You should report this to Ruby core. Please do so for the sake of the Ruby community.</strike>

As pointed out by matt, it is fixed in Ruby 2.0.0p247.

I don't see you doing anything wrong.

Comment: It looks like this is fixed in p247.

Comment: I've tried with p247 and it's working, thanks! (I'm still curious to see what was causing the problem, but I don't think I'll understand the source :P )